# What is the name of design pattern used in JSF or ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: jsf, design-patterns, webforms

Is there exist a specified name for the design pattern used in `JSF` and `ASP.NET WebForms`? Where is this design patterns describes? I want to undesrtand of using this pattern of separation bussines logic between the `view` more deeply.

Comment: [MVC](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

Comment: @kolossus So what a difference between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForms? Follow you it is the same idea in this technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **ViewEngine** Pattern. Both webforms as sjf use xhtml tags that render the html content in result